# How can I write a WHERE clause in SQL to filter a DATETIME column by the time of day (overnight)?

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm trying to filter time date from a DateTime table to create two separate tables:

- Day-shift 07AM to 07PM, and
- Night-shift 07PM to 07AM - overnight

I've been able to filter the day-shift using this query:

```
SELECT
  tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp
  ,tbLogTimeValues.SeqNo
  ,tbLogTimeValues.FloatVALUE
  ,tbLogTimeValues.ParentID
  ,tbLogTimeValues.OdometerValue
FROM tbLogTimeValues
WHERE datepart("hh", tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp) >= 07
AND datepart("hh",   tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp) <= 19
```

but I don't know how to filter for the night-shift.

Comment: If there are no null values, you can just wrap your original clause with `NOT ( . . . )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `where` clause to its inverse:

```
WHERE datepart(hour, tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp) < 07 or
      datepart(hour, tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp) > 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE datepart("hh", tbLogTimeValues.DateTimeStamp) NOT BETWEEN 7 AND 19
```

Comment: Likewise, the existing code for "day shift" can be simplified as `BETWEEN 7 AND 19`